# Return reference not copy with GetValue()

Tags: c#, object, reflection, reference, copy

using reflection in c# I need to get only reference to object, not copy, is it possible?

```
object data = actualData.GetType().GetProperty(properties[0]).GetValue(actualData, null);
```

variable data should be only reference - if I change something inside, I would like to perform the same changes in actualData variable, but it seems to copy value from actual data and any change stay only in data variable. Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure? what is the type of your property?

Comment: `GetValue` does the same thing as invoking the property explicity. It doesn't `clone` anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your property is of value type. Or maybe it is of reference type but it creates a new instance of resulting class instead of reusing it.

If this is a case, then I'm afraid this can't be done in general - properties are methods, so the result value of property is calculated, you cannot observe when that result would be changed.

But if you can change class of which `actualData` is the instance, then you can implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface and subscribe to its event `PropertyChanged` in your code.

If this is not possible then you can remember the result of ...GetProperty(), but you have to call GetValue() on it each time when you need the data.

Comment: no I can not change class actualData, because it could be almost anything - I am making generic control, which can work with many different objects, so actualData is not always the same

Comment: Then you have to recalculate `.GetValue()` every time when you use your `data` variable. But you can cache the result of GetProperty(). Sorry :(